# Permutations with fixed point conditions

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to find the number of permutations $P(10,10)$ and we have the condition that $\sigma(2i) = 2i$ for every $i\in [5]$. I though about inclusion exclusion or that we essentially hold 5 points fixed and permute the other 5 points so we would have $5!$ ways. Can anybody tell me if I am going down the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. If you fix the $5$ even, you just have to permute the $5$ odd in $5!$ ways. Inclusion-exclusion would be useful if you have **at least one** even fixed.

Comment: Would this be true for any arbitrary values then? If I had$P(25k,25k)$ with $\sigma(ki)=ki$ for $i\in [25]$

Comment: then you will have $(25k-25)!$ like you have $(2*5-5)!$ in your question. In general if you want to fix those points you just take them away. A very different exercise is if you want **at least** or **exactly** (meaning you do not want to fix the others, in which case you have to use the concept of derangement).